# continues or will continue

Tags: grammar, tense

> The forestry industry **(has met and continues)/(has met and will continue)** to meet the growing changes required to stay competitive within a rapidly transforming economy.

Should it be "continues" or "will continue"? I think both makes sense, so does it depend on the context, or is one of them wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. In my opinion, the **continues** version would be used in a reporting scenario, where the reporter is informing us of the current state of affairs in the forestry industry. The **will continue** version would be used in some kind of statement or speech from the forestry industry itself, emphasizing their commitment to maintain their competitiveness going forward.